# return const value prevent move semantics

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in cpp so excuse me for this question.

I was reading that returning const val prevents move semantics. 
therefore I dont understand why the following code is compiled and works normally. is it because only temporary object is being created? in what cases the move semantics cannot being done? thank you in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const string foo()
{
    return string("hello");
}

int main()
{
    string other = std::move(foo());
}
```

Comment: `const string foo()` makes little sense. The caller can *always* place the return value (semantically, a copy) in a non-const `string` and modify it (the copy) as they see fit. `const` on that return value is pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::move` is just a unconditional cast to rvalue. In your case the return value of `std::move(foo())` was `const std::string&&`. And because move constructor does not take const argument, copy constructor was called instead.

```cpp
struct C {
    C() { std::cout << "constructor" << std::endl; }
    C(const C& other) { std::cout << "copy constructor" << std::endl; }
    C(C&& other) { std::cout << "move constructor" << std::endl; }
};

const C get() {
    return C();
}

int main() {
    C c(std::move(get()));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @NissimLevy Please don't make "thank you" as a comment.  Upvote the answer by clicking on the arrow button instead.

Answer (score 2):

> I was reading that returning const val prevents move semantics. therefore I dont understand why the following code is compiled and works normally.

When move semantics are prevented by some mechanism, this doesn't necessarily mean that the code doesn't compile. Often, it compiles happily, but an expected move construction turns out to be a copy instead.

Example: a type has a user provided copy ctor, which disables compiler-generated move ctors. When we think we move-construct, we don't.

```
struct Test {
   Test() = default;
   Test(const Test&) {}
};

Test t1;
Test t2{std::move(t1)}; // Copies!
```

> in what cases the move semantics cannot being done?

Coming to your example, something that is `const`-qualified can't be used to move-construct another object in any meaningful way. Move construction makes sense when resources can be easily transferred, but `const`-ness prevents that. Example: a type has compiler-generate move and copy constructors, but we can't move-construct from a `const` instance.

```
struct Test {
    Test() = default;
};

const Test t1;
Test t2{std::move(t1)};  // Copies!
```

Besides, it doesn't make sense to move something that is returned by a function by value:

```
string other = std::move(foo());
```

When `foo()` returns by value, you can move-construct from it, unless the return type is `const`. Hence, to enable move-construction of `other`:

```
std::string foo();

string other = foo();
```

Comment: thank you very much for the clear explanation and examples :) was really helpfull

Answer (score 1):

`std::move` doesn't actually move anything. It is just an "rvalue cast". You cast something to rvalue, and the move constructor / move assignment operator does the actual moving **if possible**. "If possible" part is the key. In your example the return value is already an rvalue, so `std::move` literally does nothing. You may even get warnings like "nothing is moved". That is because the move constructor of `std::string` takes an argument of type `std::string&&` not `const std::string&&`. Because of that, the copy constructor is called.